# Can i obtain tags from Google Photos?

Tags: google-photos

Google Photos automatically assigns tags to images uploaded to its service. For example, if you make a photo of your cat, it will most likely identify a cat in your image and assign the "cat" label. Now if you search for "cat" in your Google Photos, it will turn up.

However, is there a way to **reverse** this. Is there a way to see *all* tags linked to a photo. In the example above, I want to see the label "cat" assigned to the image without knowing it is assigned by searching the "cat" label.

Comment: Google doesn't expose the search terms that might bring you to a specific image. Partly to protect their algorithm, I'm sure, but probably also as the algorithm learns more they'll keep changing.

Comment: This would be very useful as I'm struggling to find similar photos to mine in my own library (which is surprisingly easy to do to search pictures on the Internet, but not among your own photos!). At least knowing which tags match my "card with a reward code printed on it" would help me find all my other cards so I can redeem all the codes!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but it does seem possible as this service shows an example of pulling all the tags attributed by Google:
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/google_auto_tagging_addon

Has anyone had success doing this just from Googles api?